# Choosing statistical analysis with an ordinal DV

Tags: modeling, ordinal-data

I am struggling to determine which statistical test to use for my analysis for my dissertation. I am studying how psychologists and clergy members are taught to work with families where there has been a suicide. One of my questions address the professional’s comfort level in working with these families.

So far I have identified that I have two independent variables: year of licensure/ordination and group membership (psychologist vs. clergy). I believe they are interval and nominal variables, respectively. My dependent variable is comfort level that I have coded (0 = not comfortable/would refer, 1 = somewhat comfortable, and 2 = comfortable). I believe this is an ordinal variable.

I am looking to see if year of licensure/ordination impacts comfort level, as well as if group membership impacts comfort level. Which statistical test should I use for my analysis?

Comment: Proportional odds model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit